# Java Hibernate error persisting entity, why is that?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I want to persist entities with Hibernate. I got a problem there: when trying to persist an entity, I get the error

> Could not instantiate persister org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister

Here is my hibernate.cfg.xml, version 6.0:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
     "https://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->

        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=PurchaseDatabase;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">admin</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">admin</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Other Hibernate settings -->


        <!-- Mapping files -->
        <mapping class="com.example.purchasedatabase.ErwerbsDatenEinheit"
                 resource="ErwerbsDatenEinheit.hbm.xml" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And my corresponding *.hbm.xml file:

```xml
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
     "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
     "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"> 

 <hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="com.example.purchasedatabase.ErwerbsDatenEinheit"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
   table="ErwerbsDatenEinheiten">
     
     <meta attribute = "class-description">
        This class contains the details on the purchases we carry out.
     </meta>
     
     <id name = "ID" type = "int" column = "ID">
        <generator class="native"/>
     </id>
     
     <property name = "Rechnungsnummer" column = "Rechnungsnummer" type = "text"/>
     <property name = "Name" column = "Name" type = "text"/>
     <property name = "Hersteller" column = "Hersteller" type = "text"/>
     <property name = "DatumKauf" column = "DatumKauf" type = "text"/>
     <property name = "Menge" column = "Menge" type = "Double"/>
     <property name = "Kosten" column = "Kosten" type = "Double"/>
     <property name = "DatumAnkunft" column = "DatumAnkunft" type = "text"/>
     <property name = "Bemerkung" column = "Bemerkung" type = "text"/>
     <property name = "Deaktiviert" column = "Deaktiviert" type = "Boolean"/>
     
   </class>
 </hibernate-mapping>
```

And my actual class that should be mapped:

```java
package com.example.purchasedatabase;

//import org.hibernate.annotations.Entity;
//import org.hibernate.annotations.Table;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name = "ErwerbsDatenEinheiten")
public class ErwerbsDatenEinheit {

    @Id
    private int ID;

    @Column
    private String DatumKauf;

    @Column
    private String Rechnungsnummer;

    @Column
    private String Hersteller;

    @Column
    private String Name;

    @Column
    private double Kosten;

    @Column
    private double Menge;

    @Column
    private String DatumAnkunft;

    @Column
    private String Bemerkung;

    @Column
    private boolean Deaktiviert;


    public ErwerbsDatenEinheit(){
        this.ID = 0;
        this.DatumKauf = "";
        this.Rechnungsnummer = "";
        this.Hersteller = "";
        this.Name = "";
        this.Kosten = 0;
        this.Menge = 0;
        this.DatumAnkunft = "";
        this.Bemerkung = "";
        this.Deaktiviert = false;
    }


    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getDatumKauf() {
        return DatumKauf;
    }

    public void setDatumKauf(String datumKauf) {
        DatumKauf = datumKauf;
    }

    public String getRechnungsnummer() {
        return Rechnungsnummer;
    }

    public void setRechnungsnummer(String rechnungsnummer) {
        Rechnungsnummer = rechnungsnummer;
    }

    public String getHersteller() {
        return Hersteller;
    }

    public void setHersteller(String hersteller) {
        Hersteller = hersteller;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public double getKosten() {
        return Kosten;
    }

    public void setKosten(double kosten) {
        Kosten = kosten;
    }

    public double getMenge() {
        return Menge;
    }

    public void setMenge(double menge) {
        Menge = menge;
    }

    public String getDatumAnkunft() {
        return DatumAnkunft;
    }

    public void setDatumAnkunft(String datumAnkunft) {
        DatumAnkunft = datumAnkunft;
    }

    public String getBemerkung() {
        return Bemerkung;
    }


    public void setBemerkung(String bemerkung) {
        Bemerkung = bemerkung;
    }

    public boolean isDeaktiviert() {
        return Deaktiviert;
    }

    public void setDeaktiviert(boolean deaktiviert) {
        Deaktiviert = deaktiviert;
    }
}
```

The hibernate.cfg.xml gets recognized in a Configuration object.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: Solved it: The classes property are not allowed to be private !